# $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R, f\in C^1$ then $f$ perserves measurability

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, lipschitz-functions

There's some ambiguity around these terms so I'll be as clear as I can.

A set $A \subseteq R$ is said to be negligible if for all $\epsilon > 0$ there are boxes $Q_1, Q_2, \dots$ such that $A \subset \bigcup Q_i$ and $\sum V(Q_i) < \epsilon$

A set $E \subseteq \mathbb R$ is said to be Jordan measurable if $\partial E$ is negligible.

The proposition I wish to prove is that if $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is $C^1$ and $E \subset \mathbb R$ is Jordan measurable then $f(E)$ is also Jordan measurable.

**What I tried:**

Not sure if this is the correct direction. Let $\epsilon > 0$. $E$ is Jordan measurable so there are closed intervals $I_1, I_2, \dots$ such that $\partial E \subset \bigcup I_k$ and $\sum V(I_k) < \epsilon$.

$f$ is $C^1$ on $I_k$ and so it's Lipschitz there. We know that Lipschitz functions map negligible sets to negligible sets, and so $f(I_k)$ is negligible for all $k$.

It is clear to see now that $f(\partial E) \subset\bigcup f(I_k)$ is negligible, since it's a countable union of negligible sets.

But we weren't asked about $f(\partial E)$. We were asked about $\partial f(E)$. Is there any relation between the two? If $f$ is a diffeomorphism, then I know that they are equal. But can we say anything when $f$ is not know to be invertible, but rather just $C^1$?

Comment: I think $f$ needs to be injective, i.e $f'(x) \neq 0 $ for any $x$. This would allow you to use the inverse function theorem.

Comment: Then how would you prove this without knowing injectivity?

Comment: I don't think it's true necessarily.

Comment: That's quite a claim. It's a question from an exam. Though I suppose mistakes do happen every now and then.

Comment: In general, it seems you want to show that $f(\partial E) \subset \partial f(E)$ but this is not true without injectivity.

Comment: Actually I want to show the other way around if possible, that would solve the problem.

Comment: Consider $\{f'>0\}$ and $\{f´=0\}$. You can apply the inverse function theorem on the first set but the second set is not workable, I guess. Sard's theorem shows it has Lebesgue measure zero but nothing really can be said about its Jordan measure